How can I pass a prop from child component to parent component to another child component?
I am working on a project that has a Header component and a Main component. The Header component has links that are supposed to open individual pages. The pages (other components) are supposed to be within the Main component. I need to pass to the main component a value showing what link in the Header component was clicked. The Header and Main components are siblings on page.tsx. Here is the relevant code:
Header.tsx
const Header = () => {
  let sectionsObject = {
    showServiceDesk: true,
    showLeadSupport: false, 
    showClaimsDisbursements: false,
    showProductDescription: false,
    showSuppression: false
  }   
  const [sectionsToExpand, setSectionsToExpand] = useState(sectionsObject);
  function expandSection(sectionClicked: string) { 
    Object.keys(sectionsObject).map((key) => {
        if (key === sectionClicked) {
            setSectionsToExpand((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                [key]: !prevState[key]
            }))
        } else {
            setSectionsToExpand((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                [key]: false
            }))
        }
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(sectionsToExpand));
  }
  return (
        <AppBar position='static' sx={{bgcolor: '#E8E8E8', color:'rgb(0 0 0 / 50%)', fontSize: '1rem', fontWeight: '400'}}>
          <Toolbar>       
            <Box sx={{display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex'}}}>
              <Button color='inherit' sx={{ fontSize: '1rem', fontWeight: '400'}} onClick={() => expandSection('showServiceDesk')} className={ `nav-link ${sectionsToExpand.showServiceDesk ? 'expanded' : ''}`}>Service Desk</Button>
              <Button color='inherit' sx={{ fontSize: '1rem', fontWeight: '400'}} onClick={() => expandSection('showLeadSupport')} className={ `nav-link  ${sectionsToExpand.showLeadSupport ? 'expanded' : ''}`}>Lead Support</Button>
              <Button color='inherit' sx={{ fontSize: '1rem', fontWeight: '400'}} onClick={() => expandSection('showClaimsDisbursements')} className={ `nav-link  ${sectionsToExpand.showClaimsDisbursements ? 'expanded' : ''}`}>Claims/Disbursements</Button>
              <Button color='inherit' sx={{ fontSize: '1rem', fontWeight: '400'}} onClick={() => expandSection('showProductDescription')} className={ `nav-link  ${sectionsToExpand.showProductDescription ? 'expanded' : ''}`}>Product Description</Button>
              <Button color='inherit' sx={{ fontSize: '1rem', fontWeight: '400'}} onClick={() => expandSection('showSuppression')} className={ `nav-link  ${sectionsToExpand.showSuppression ? 'expanded' : ''}`}>Suppression</Button>
            </Box>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    )
}
export default Header

Here is the page.tsx. The lines marked with asterisks were my attempt to get my issue working.
export default function Home() {
  const [config, setConfig] = useState<config | null>(null);
  *** let sectionsObject = {
    *** showServiceDesk: true,
    *** showLeadSupport: false,
    *** showClaimsDisbursements: false,
    *** showProductDescription: false,
    *** showSuppression: false
  *** } 
  *** const [sectionsToExpand, setSectionsToExpand] = useState(sectionsObject);
  *** console.log('Header - sectionsToExpand = ' + JSON.stringify(sectionsToExpand));
  useEffect(() => {
    getConfigUrls();
  }, []);
  const getConfigUrls = () => {
    ConfigService.getInstance().getConfigs().then((response) => {
      setConfig(response);
    });
  };
  return (
      <>
      <Header *** sectionsToExpand = {sectionsToExpand} setSectionsToExpand = {setSectionsToExpand} *** />
      <Main config = {config} *** sectionsToExpand = {sectionsToExpand} *** />
      </>
  );
}

Main.tsx (the ellipses are where there is code that I think is not relevant):
export const Main = ({config} : {config : config}, *** {sectionsToExpand: {}} *** ) => {
  ...
  *** const [sectionsToExpand, setSectionsToExpand] = useState();
  ...
  return (
    <main className="tw-p-4 tw-mt-7"> 
      <Stack gap={2}>
        {/* Customer search Section */}
        <CustomerSearch ... />
        {/* Customer details Tabs Section */}
        {selectedCustomers.length > 0 ? (
          <Customer Tab
            ...
          />
        ) : null}
        < /* THIS IS WHERE I THINK I NEED SEPARATE COMPONENTS FOR LEAD ENTRY, PRODUCT DESCRIPTION, ETC */ />
      </Stack>
    </main>
  );
};

Two things to note:
First, when I click on one of the links in Header, the console.log in page.tsx fires, and the logged object shows that the correct property in sectionsObject is marked true. So I appear to be passing the value correctly from the child Header to the parent page.tsx.
Second, in page.tsx, where the Main component is, the code I added (sectionsToExpand = {sectionsToExpand}) shows an error on the first sectionsToExpand. Here is the error:
 TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'sectionsToExpand' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.

In VS Code itself, I get the following error:
Type '{ config: config; sectionsToExpand: { showServiceDesk: boolean; showClaimsDisbursements: boolean; showLeadEntry: boolean; showProductDescription: boolean; showSuppression: boolean; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { config: config; }'.
  Property 'sectionsToExpand' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { config: config; }'.

My goal is to pass down the sectionsObject and use whichever property has true on it at the time to show the component it represents while hiding the others.
Any help is appreciated.
